# RabbitMQ startup error on OS X Leopard

Tags: rabbitmq

Can anyone help diagnose why RabbitMQ is failing to start?  It has worked fine in the past, but suddenly is refusing to start.  I'm running the command `sudo rabbitmqctl start`, and I get the following output:

```
Error: {'EXIT',
       {function_clause,
           [{rabbit_control,action,
                [start,rabbit@BELLOMACPRO,[],
                 [{"-p","/"},{"-n","rabbit@BELLOMACPRO"},{"-q",false}],
                 #Fun<rabbit_control.1.100323439>],
                [{file,"src/rabbit_control.erl"},{line,168}]},
            {rabbit_control,start,0,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_control.erl"},{line,84}]},
            {init,start_it,1,[]},
            {init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
```

I'm not finding this particularly informative, but perhaps there's something obvious to someone who better understands Erlang.  The log file has no recent entries to shed any light on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out what the cause of the problem was, but I worked around it by executing the server directly with `sudo rabbitmq-server`, rather than attempting to use `rabbitmqctl`.  Explanations are still welcome.